# Why / how can I page show the page when I have the prefix "view-source:"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I just clicked on "view source" in Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) of the non-public part of a JavaScript heavy website and it showed me the page itself again, not the code.

How does it do so?

(When I open the developer tools I get the normal / expected behaviour)

Comment: Doesn't do that for me.

Comment: It doesn't do so for me for any other website either. It might be a Chrome bug, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes something like that definitely seems like a bug, or at least a pretty weird "feature".

Comment: Firefox 54.0 (64-bit) does not have the same behaviour. Any idea how to investigate it / report it without spending too much time? (I can't give the credentials to that site to others, sorry)

Comment: Does it happen only in specified version ?  What about latest chromium and canary ? Can't you scrap this webpage in order to find the offending bit ?

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce it after switching "Quick Javascript Switcher 1.4.1" off and on again. I'm voting to close because of "off topic -> can't reproduce"

Comment: @MartinThoma, yo know you can simply delete your question instead of waiting fro CVers and rumba to take care of it.